# SQL - CURDATE() + 4 random digits (2013-10-02-0001)

Tags: mysql, sql, date, unique

```
create table Table1(

DateIdentify CHAR(15),
primary key(DateIdentify)

);

Insert into Table1 (DateIdentify) VALUES('?');
```

How I want the 'DateIdentify' to look: (20131002-0001) with 0001 being some sort of an auto incrementer that starts at 0001 and goes up every insert and 20131002 coming from CURDATE(), so adding CURDATE() + 4 digits. I'm wondering if this is possible? If so, could anyone please point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(

  IdTable1  int auto_increment NOT NULL,
  Date1 datetime,

);
```

Comment: DateTime, not string....

Comment: Do yourself a favour and store date and key sperately.

Comment: can you use two fields instead? one for the date and the other one for your id?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I should've added that I'm very new to SQL. So I should maybe have two fields? Like Date DATETIME and DateIdentify CHAR(4)? And try to add these together somehow? I'm using MYSQL

Comment: Does the number part have to start from 0001 every change of date?

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate your datetime and the auto increment field.
Create your table like this using an auto-increment int field, and your datetime.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(
  IdTable1  int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  Date      datetime
)
```

Then, you don't have to insert anything in `IdTable1` because of it is auto-incremented thanks to keyword `IDENTITY` (SQL do the auto-increment for you)

**NOTE :** I wrote this for SQLServer, if you use another database, the code can change a little bit. 
**Which one do you use ?**

EDIT :
You can also do some insert like this :

```
INSERT INTO Table1
(
    Date
)
VALUES
(
    '2013-10-02'
)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but the datatype IDENTIFY is new to me. Do you mind demostrating how an Insert would look with the example you showed? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: `IDENTIFY` is an auto-increment property in SQLServer syntax. Here, the auto-increment begins at 1 and has a step of 1.

Comment: since this is tagged as `mysql` you would need to replace `IDENTITY(1,1)` with `auto_increment` to have equivalent behavior

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this works if I'm honest. How does 'idTable1' add onto the 'Date' and combine the two? Check my EDIT above, is this correct? If so, how would the insert look in MySQL?

Comment: You don't have to combine both. This is very ugly. Your `auto-increment` field must be a separate field, it's a best practice you must adopt. Just try it with your MySQL, you'll understand

Comment: Alright, having two seperate fields makes alot of sense now that I think about it. Thanks alot for the help.

Comment: @ErikÅstrand You're welcome. Don't forget to validate this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

In case a solution is required as, having only one column with values in desired format you can create a function as:

```
 create function dbo.fn_GetDateIdentify ()
 returns varchar(15)
 as
 begin
 declare @DateIdentify varchar(15);

 select @DateIdentify =  
         (select convert (varchar(8),GETDATE (),112) +
         '-' + 
         right ('00000' + cast (
                               (
                               ( 
                               case when Not exists (select ROW_NUMBER() over( order by (select 1)) from Table1 ) then 1 
                               else (select top 1 ROW_NUMBER() over( order by (select 1)) as currentRownumber from Table1 order by currentRownumber desc) + 1
                               end   
                               ) 
                               )
                               as varchar(4))
                ,4));
return @DateIdentify;
end
go;
```

and then use the function in insert statement as :

```
 insert into Table1 (DateIdentify) 
 select dbo.fn_GetDateIdentify();
```

Hope this helps!